# How to properly access props inside a component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to access `user` object inside `NavBar.js`. Below is the code which is working but kinds feels dirty as I have to do `data.user.children[0].props.user` in the `NavBar.js` component to access user object. I would like to access it as `props.user` if possible. Below is my code.

```js
//NavBar.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";

const NavBar = (data) => {
    console.log("inside NavBar")
    console.log(data.user.children[0].props.user) //<--this does not feel right. Can't it be accessed as props.user?

    return (
        <Menu>
            <Menu.Item
                name='home'
                content='Home'
                href="/"
            />

            <Menu.Item
                name='whoami'
                content='Who Am I?'
                href="/whoami"
            />

        </Menu>

    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

```js
//Layout.js
import { Container, Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
const Layout = (props) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column>
                        <NavBar user={props}></NavBar> //<--I am sure I am doing something wrong here
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column>
                        {props.children}
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>

        </Container>
    )
};

export default Layout;
```

```js
//_app.js
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </Layout>
  )
};

export default MyApp;
```

As you can see I have `Layout.js` which has `NavBar.js` component and I am sure I am not adding it the right way.

I am not a react developer so I am guessing this code snippet is enough for someone to guide me. I can add more code if needed.

Comment: The recommended pattern is to be explicit about what props you are passing, and to only pass the props that a component needs. For example, if `Layout` only needs `children` and the necessary user for the NavBar you can use destructuring to only extract the props you need from the incoming prop object: `const Layout = ({children, userData}) => {...`. Like wise, when passing props to NavBar only pass the user that is needed. `<NavBar user={userData.user} \>`. Doing this means you can glance at a Component element and have a fairly clear idea of what is happening on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the props from the children, you can send the same props to the Layout component. Then you can reach the user directly by destructuring the props.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
     /** send same props */
    <Layout {...pageProps}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </Layout>
  )
};

export default MyApp;

//Layout.js
import { Container, Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
/** destructure user */
const Layout = ({user}) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column>
                        /** send user again */
                        <NavBar user={user}></NavBar> //<--I am sure I am doing something wrong here
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column>
                        {props.children}
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>

        </Container>
    )
};

export default Layout;

//NavBar.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";

const NavBar = ({user}) => {
    /** Use the user prop directly */
    console.log("inside NavBar", user)
    return (
        <Menu>
            <Menu.Item
                name='home'
                content='Home'
                href="/"
            />

            <Menu.Item
                name='whoami'
                content='Who Am I?'
                href="/whoami"
            />

        </Menu>

    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be more correct (if the structure of the props data is correct)

```
<NavBar user={props.user}></NavBar>
```

and

```
const NavBar = (user) => {
console.log("inside NavBar")
console.log(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of what's in your Layout props but maybe you do something like this:

```
<NavBar user={props.user.children[0].props.user}></NavBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you props deconstructing. It seems that NavBar component needs only user property, so you can pass it in your Layout.

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  let {
    user
  } = props.user.children[0].props;

  return(
    ...
    <NavBar user={user}></NavBar>
  )
}
```

Then in NavBar component you directly access user.

```
const NavBar = (user) => {
  console.log(user)
}
```